# Finding specific row in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM extensiondata WHERE name="Post To Tumblr";
```

Generates this error:

```
ERROR:  column "Post To Tumblr" does not exist
```

I have a column called name. As far as I know `where name="search"` should find a row where the column name is equal to search. So what is amiss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name = 'Post To Tumblr'
```

Use single quotes for values. Double quotes are used for identifiers.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS